# The equivalence between two expressions of asymmetric coupling-based distance

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, coupling

Why is
$$
C(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P}):=\inf _{\mathbb{M}} \sqrt{\int \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\mathbb{M}\left[Y_{i} \neq x_{i} \mid X_{i}=x_{i}\right]\right)^{2} d \mathbb{P}(x)}
$$
where the infimum ranges over all couplings $\mathbb{M}$ of the pair $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})$.

equivalent to
$$
C(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})=\sqrt{\int\left|1-\frac{d \mathbb{Q}}{d \mathbb{P}}(x)\right|_{+}^{2} d \mathbb{P}(x)}
$$
where $t_{+}:=\max\{0, t\}$.

? This result is presented in Section 3.3.5 of the book *High-dimensional statistics: A non-asymptotic viewpoint(Wainwright, 2019)*.

Answer (score 0):

**Short explanation:** Both sides are measures of the total variational distance

Note: This is just an attempt at explanation. Maybe someone more knowledgeable than me in this area can write a much better answer.

---

**Setting:**
First the author takes up a simpler instance: a single random variable $X$ in section 3.3.1

$(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})$ are probability distributions over $X$. $\mathbb M$ is a distribution on the product space $X \otimes X$ is a coupling on the pair  $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})$ if the marginal distrubutions of $\mathbb M$ on the first and second coordinates coincide with $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})$ respectively.

In fact, by (3.55), $\int f(d\mathbb Q - d\mathbb P) = \inf\limits_{\mathbb M}\mathbb E_{\mathbb M}[\rho(X,X')]$

Now we go from 1 random variable $X$ to a sequence of random variables: $\{X_1,\dots X_n\}$ (generated by a markov chain) in section 3.3.4. We wish to find the total variational distance between two distributions $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{P})$ on these n random variables.

Finally note the definition of the Radon Nikodym derivative (which gives the definition of $\frac{d \mathbb Q}{d \mathbb P}$). This is defined in section 3.3.2 of the book.

---

**The first expression is a measure of the distance between two distributions**

For an explanation on why the infimum over the coupling probabilities (where $X\neq Y$) is the total variational distance, see [lemma 4.11 from this document by Sebastien Roch](https://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Eroch/mdp/roch-mdp-chap4.pdf) here:

$||\mathbb P - \mathbb Q||_{TV} = \inf\{Prob(x\neq y) \text{ coupling (X,Y) of }\mathbb P\text{ and }\mathbb Q)\}$.

Also see proposition 1.7 of [this linked document by Parimal Parag](https://ece.iisc.ac.in/%7Eparimal/2019/statphy/lecture-14.pdf)

In our case we have to sum these over the n random variables $\{X_1,\dots ,X_n\}$.

Note: The linked file also has some good explanations on what coupling means

---

**The second expression is a measure of the wasserstein distance between two distributions**

Note the outer part of the formula comes from the definition of wasserstein distance. There are various types of wasserstein distance. See table 1 in this [linked document by Yuhang Cai and Lek-Heng Lim](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/work/probdist.pdf) for various measures used and the one in the text in the second expression.

---

With this in mind, we have that both are different measures of the divergence between distributions. Are they equivalent? See lemma 2 of [this attached document by PM Samson](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1019160125)